# summarize by_group within a range and output values back into full data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Long time listener, first time caller. I have a probably simple question but am banging my head against the wall trying to solve it. My data looks like this:

```
    SUBJ HEMI  TIME   stimulus spikes
1 E2M022 L     -2.00  REV.BOS     11
2 E2M022 L     -1.99  REV.BOS     11
3 E2M022 L     -1.98  REV.BOS     12
4 E2M022 L     -1.97  REV.BOS      1
5 E2M022 L     -1.96  REV.BOS      6
6 E2M022 L     -1.95  REV.BOS      3
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- **First,** group_by SUBJ + HEMI + stimulus (e.g. E2M022-R-NCM; E2M022-L-NCM; etc.)
- **Then,** sum the number of spikes for a specific range of time (e.g -2 to  -0.01), and divide that summed # by 2 (e.g. baseline_Hz)
- **Finally,** return the new value (e.g. baseline_Hz) to the df as a new column, so it might look something like this:

  ```
  SUBJ   HEMI  TIME  stimulus   spikes   baseline_Hz
  E2M022 L    -2.00  REV.BOS    11       8
  E2M022 L    -1.99  REV.BOS    9        8
  ...
  E2M022 R    -2.00  REV.BOS    7        6
  E2M022 R    -1.99  REV.BOS    2        6
  ...
  E2M019 L    -2.00  REV.BOS    2        3
  E2M019 L    -1.99  REV.BOS    14       3
  ```

It would yield a lot of repeated values for each subj/hemi/stimulus but I think it makes the most sense for my data. I've tried doing it with `{dplyr}` with the following code and can successfully filter a give time range, e.g.:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(inrange(TIME, -2, -0.01))
```

But if I try to summarize by_group, I run into issues:

```
df %>%
  filter(inrange(TIME, -2,-0.01)) %>%
  group_by(SUBJ, HEMI, stimulus, add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(baseline_Hz = sum(spikes))
```

Output is just a sum of all spikes instead of by subj/hemi/stimulus:

```
  baseline_Hz
1       21914
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot, you should find where the issue is sourced. The issue comes from your filter actually, not after. If you remove the filter and do

```
 df %>%
     group_by(SUBJ, HEMI, stimulus, add = TRUE) %>%
     summarise(baseline_Hz = sum(spikes))
```

you get

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   SUBJ, HEMI [?]
  SUBJ   HEMI  stimulus baseline_Hz
  <fct>  <fct> <fct>          <dbl>
1 E2M020 L     REV.BOS            9
2 E2M021 L     REV.BOS           13
3 E2M022 L     REV.BOS           22
```

instead of

```
SUBJ HEMI TIME stimulus spikes
1 E2M022    L   -2  REV.BOS     11
```

The answer would be to change your filter to `filter(TIME <= -.01 & TIME >= -2)%>%`

This looks like:

```
> df %>%
+     filter(TIME <= -.01 & TIME >= -2)%>%
+     group_by(SUBJ, HEMI, stimulus, add = TRUE) %>%
+     summarise(baseline_Hz = sum(spikes))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   SUBJ, HEMI [?]
  SUBJ   HEMI  stimulus baseline_Hz
  <fct>  <fct> <fct>          <dbl>
1 E2M020 L     REV.BOS            9
2 E2M021 L     REV.BOS           13
3 E2M022 L     REV.BOS           22
```

Hope this helps (I think the filters were looking for full integers, I tried `inrange()` and `%in%` but they looked for full digits)...

Comment: Thanks @albert-pariente-cohen! I'm really baffled how both you and @Sam are able to yield `subj` x `hemi` x `stimulus` values. I tried previously running without the `inrange()` or `filter` and still this is what it evaluates to:

     `baseline_Hz`
  `1       88719`

(sorry for the formatting, I'm still getting used to Markdown w/o a preview window!)

Comment: Are you saving the column names as "SUBJ" = c() ? I'm not sure what you are doing to cause that, but that is possibly it? Can you paste the full output that comes when you try the above? I.e. the tibble information?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "saving the column names as "SUBJ" = c() ?", sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm struggling to add block code to a comment, but essential if I run this:
`df %>%  group_by(SUBJ, HEMI, stimulus, add = TRUE) %>% summarise(baseline_Hz = sum(spikes))`

to the `tibble` data (as supplied by @Sam), I get this:
`  baseline_Hz`
`1          44`

Comment: Disregard the above actually... I figured out why you aren't getting it back. You installed plyr after dplyr I'm pretty sure. Try:

`df1 %>%
    filter(TIME <= -.01 & TIME >= -2) %>%
    group_by(SUBJ, HEMI, stimulus, add = TRUE) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(baseline_Hz = sum(spikes))`

Comment: No problem, I kept running into issues with plyr. For the future, make sure library(dplyr) is after library(plyr) in your code :)

Comment: Also, to understand my mistake, the order in which I installed the packages compromises functionality?

Comment: Yes, the package will say certain things are masked. This is what comes up after you install dplyr then plyr: `The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise, summarize`

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with the `inrange` function (which I haven't seen before?). Knocked up the following based on your example (changed up some of the data to get actual groups).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(~SUBJ, ~HEMI,  ~TIME,   ~stimulus, ~spikes,
        "E2M022", "L",     -2.00,  "REV.BOS",     11,
        "E2M022", "L",     -1.99,  "REV.BOS",     11,
        "E2M022", "L",     -1.98,  "REV.BOS",     12,
        "E2M021", "L",     -1.97,  "REV.BOS",      1,
        "E2M021", "L",     -1.96,  "REV.BOS2",      6,
        "E2M021", "L",     -1.95,  "REV.BOS2",      3,)


df %>% 
  filter(TIME > -2,
         TIME < -0.01) %>% 
         {inner_join(., 
                     group_by(., SUBJ, HEMI, stimulus) %>%
                       summarise(baseline_Hz = sum(spikes)))}
```

Which gives,

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  SUBJ   HEMI   TIME stimulus spikes baseline_Hz
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1 E2M022 L     -1.99 REV.BOS      11          23
2 E2M022 L     -1.98 REV.BOS      12          23
3 E2M021 L     -1.97 REV.BOS       1           1
4 E2M021 L     -1.96 REV.BOS2      6           9
5 E2M021 L     -1.95 REV.BOS2      3           9
```

**With inrange**

Just found `inrange` in `data.table`. Testing it in the above gives the following ,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(data.table)

df <- tribble(~SUBJ, ~HEMI,  ~TIME,   ~stimulus, ~spikes,
        "E2M022", "L",     -2.00,  "REV.BOS",     11,
        "E2M022", "L",     -1.99,  "REV.BOS",     11,
        "E2M022", "L",     -1.98,  "REV.BOS",     12,
        "E2M021", "L",     -1.97,  "REV.BOS",      1,
        "E2M021", "L",     -1.96,  "REV.BOS2",      6,
        "E2M021", "L",     -1.95,  "REV.BOS2",      3,)


df %>% 
  filter(inrange(TIME, -2, -0.01, incbounds = FALSE)) %>% 
         {inner_join(., 
                     group_by(., SUBJ, HEMI, stimulus) %>%
                       summarise(baseline_Hz = sum(spikes)))}
```

Which gives,

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  SUBJ   HEMI   TIME stimulus spikes baseline_Hz
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1 E2M022 L     -1.99 REV.BOS      11          23
2 E2M022 L     -1.98 REV.BOS      12          23
3 E2M021 L     -1.97 REV.BOS       1           1
4 E2M021 L     -1.96 REV.BOS2      6           9
5 E2M021 L     -1.95 REV.BOS2      3           9
```

So looks like everything is working as expected there.

Comment: Thank you, Sam! I think it's the way I've installed/loaded my packages and my newb R skills. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Yup seems likely - no worries happens to everyone. Always good to restart R when something like this is happening.